# Linux kernel module modpost compiling error

Tags: c, linux, module, linux-kernel, kernel

I am trying to compile this toy code to import the switch_to function, but i get this error:

```
ERROR: modpost: "__switch_to_asm" undefined!
```

This is my test.c file:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h> 
#include <asm/switch_to.h>

MODULE_DESCRIPTION("test");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("test");

#define MODULE_NAME_LOG "test: "

static int my_module_init(void)
{
    struct task_struct *test;
    switch_to(test, test, test);

    return 0;
}

static void my_module_exit(void)
{
    printk(KERN_DEBUG MODULE_NAME_LOG "exit");
}

module_init(my_module_init);
module_exit(my_module_exit);
```

This is my Makefile:

```
KDIR = /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
obj-m += test.o

all:
    make -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) clean
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: The symbol has not been exported for use by modules.